# UIScrollView. How do I disambiguate between pinch-in and pinch-out zooming?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have an app where I need to programmatically prevent pinch-in while allowing pinch-out to happen. Is there a way to disambiguate between pinch-in and pinch-out zooming?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

(1) Using `UIScrollView`. You'll need to implement `UIScrollViewDelegate`. There, in `scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`, you can compare the current zoomScale value with the previous one. If it increased, then the user is zooming in. Otherwise, the user is zooming out. Then you can do something depending on that.

(2) Using a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`. The logic in this case will be much the same (just add a similar check to see if the pinch scale is going up or down).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base-code for this. This might require some refactoring to achieve exact functionality which you require

```
// Disable existing recognizer

for (UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer in [_scrollView gestureRecognizers]) {


    if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        [recognizer setEnabled:NO];
    }
}

// Add our own

UIPinchGestureRecognizer* pinchRecognizer = 
  [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                            action:@selector(pinch:)];
[_scrollView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
[pinchRecognizer release];

- (void) pinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)recognizer { 

   if (lastScale < [recognizer scale]) {

   // pinch - out // write your own code here
   }
   else (lastScale > [recognizer scale]) {

   // pinch - in // write your own code here
   }
}

}
```

Hope this will help you to handle pinch event as per your requirement.

Comment: Solution given by @BlackRider is also correct and preferable.